# Esperar que termine una subscripcion antes de continuar un metodo (angular)

Tags: angular

Desde hace tiempo estoy lidiando con este tipo de situaciones pero nunca he sabido como solucionarla correctamente.

No pondre codigo pero si tratare de explicar.

Mi problema radica en cuando quiero realizar una subscripcion dentro de un metodo, este metodo continua antes de finalizar la subscripcion.

Ejemplo:

```
actualizar(){

declara variables y hace X cosas(paso 1)


subscripcion(data=>{ (paso 2) //Voy a buscar data para validar

realiza validaciones(paso 4) // segun la data mando error o no
})


fin del metodo (paso 3) // hace otras cosas anexas, mensaje actualizacion correcta


}
```

En mi caso estoy usando un metodo de actualizar. Este metodo actualizar hace muchas cosas en un flujo normal, pero hay un caso en el cual debo lanzar un error y que no se actualice.

Para ello mediante un subscribe voy a buscar data a la DB, y con ella determino si mando error de actualizacion o no.

El problema es que el metodo actualizar, ejecuta el subscribe, pero antes de validarlo, continua con su ejecucion actualizacion correctamente (asumiendo el flujo normal), y al final de todo se va a validar lo dentro de la subscripcion, dandome el error que quiero advertir. Entonces concluyendo me queda algo como:

```
Actualizar()


mensaje: Se ha actualizado correctamente!
mensaje: Error no se pudo actualizar.
```

¿Como puedo manejar el subscribe para que se evalue y termine antes de continuar el metodo?.

PD: No puedo meter el resto del metodo dentro del subscribe por que va por camino aparte.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Convierte el observable en una promesa y usa `await`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Como podria aplicarse eso?, algun ejemplo?